# Compile lantern for android on shell

Tags: android, gradle, compilation, expand, arr

When I executed `env=/usr/local/share/android-sdk proxychains4 make android-debug`, Build failed with an exception
    Execution failed for task ':sdk:prepareLiblanternLibrary'.

> Could not expand ZIP '/src/github.com/getlantern/lantern-devel/MobileSDK/sdk/libs/liblantern.aar'.

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: is `src/github.com/getlantern/lantern-devel/MobileSDK/sdk/libs/liblantern.aar` valid aar file ? (from https://forums.estimote.com/t/gradle-error-android-studio/1055)

Comment: How can I validate the arr file in command line environment? I have seen somebody succeed in compiling the popular project from GitHub. So I think it should be a valid file.